# Differentiating/Integrating Power Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have the following question for my math homework, and I have no clue how to solve it. I've watched videos, looked in my textbook, Quizlets, etc.

**Question:** Find the power series representation for g centered at 0 by differentiating or integrating the power series for f​ (perhaps more than​ once). Give the interval of convergence for the resulting series.
$$
g(x)=\frac{x}{(1+13x^2)^2} \text{ using } f(x)=\frac{1}{1+13x^2}
$$

I know that the power series of $f(x)$ is:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-13)^kx^{2k}
$$

I also know that the derivative of $f(x)$ is:
$$
f'(x)=\frac{-26x}{(1+13x^2)^2}
$$

However, I do not know how to relate these variations of $f(x)$ to $g(x)$, so I can find the power series of $g(x)$.

Comment: $g = \frac{-1}{26}  f'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We already have that $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-13)^kx^{2k}, |x|<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{13}}$$

It is well known that power series are differentiable within their interval of convergence and differentiating term by term gives the power series for the derivative.

In other words, $$f'(x)=\frac{-26x}{(1+13x^2)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2k(-13)^kx^{2k-1} $$

But $g(x)=\dfrac{x}{(1+13x^2)^2}=\dfrac{-f'}{26}$, so $$g(x)=-\dfrac{1}{26}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2k(-13)^kx^{2k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k(-13)^{k-1}x^{2k-1} ,\space  |x|<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{13}}$$

By shifting the index, we finally get $$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(-13)^{k}x^{2k+1} ,\space  |x|<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{13}}$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to avoid the relation between $f$ and $g,$ although the method of differentiation is the fastest one. Namely we have
$${1\over 1- y}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n,\quad |y|<1$$
By applying the Cauchy product we obtain
$${1\over (1-y)^2} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n y^ky^{n-k}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)y^n,\ |y|<1$$ Substituting $y:=-13x^2$ and multiplying by $x$ gives
$${x\over (1+13x^2)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(-1)^n13^nx^{2n+1} $$
under assumption $|y|=13x^2<1,$ i.e. $|x|<13^{-1/2}.$